# AngularJS / Angular 6 Hybrid App Duplicate Console Error Messages

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular6, angular-hybrid

See image below. I assume it's because it's an hybrid app that it would push out errors twice but then again I could be wrong about that. Has anyone encountered this before?

Why are errors being printed twice?

[image: Duplicate console errors]

Comment: Open up both `ProgramModule` and `GroupModule`, and check the `declarations` array, because the same component (`SpinLoaderComponent`) is being included in both, where it should only be in one

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to avoid duplicate console log error messages, errors get posted twice, no matter what the error is. Makes reading errors hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `window.webpackJsonp` to see if it contains multiples of your node_modules. If it does then this would suggest that it's including the modules twice and so calling the same methods that output to the console.

Comment: I don't seem to have that file in my project. I have a `webpack.config.js`

Comment: In your browser debug console. This would be a property of the window object, not a file.

Comment: Hey, sry for the late reply but I cannot find this, could you perhaps post a screenshot image with an example?

Comment: Steps: 1. `ng new test-app` 2. `ng serve --open` 3. Open your web brewer's inspector/console and type `console.log(window.webpackJsonp);` press enter. Result: Should be an object with some Arrays. Notes: This is if you have a fresh install of angular-cli and `ng new` is functioning as it would by default.